# Show post background on hover Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

It's actually very simple, yet when you're not so hot at PHP and JS like me, it gets complicated.

I have a link list of posts which is generated with PHP in WordPress dynamically. Each of those links has a featured image which is in fact the background of the link list.

```html
<div style="dynamically produced background from featured image that I want to change on hover">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>WP post link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>WP post link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So in other words, when one hovers over the links, I want the background to change.

Any ideas about the JS behind this?